# You can see me - What am I?

Tags: riddle

```
I have a mouth but can't eat 

I run but don't walk 

I have a bed but can't sleep
```

What am I?

Comment: this is my first time doing this so it might not be very good

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, Roxann! This looks like a good enough first riddle to me, though I did have to correct the tags. Feel free to take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site, and I hope you enjoy your stay!